# Does a file with Build Action=Content gets loaded to memory at execution time?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I have an app with lots of files with `Build Action` property set to `Content`. When I analyze it, I see it needs lots of memory So I doubt that these files are the cause.

Does such these files, get loaded to memory at execution time or just when we access them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `Content` isn't like `Resource`. It is not embedded within the application-binary. This is useful when you want to copy additional files like images or other external files you want to include in you solution, but not touched by the compiler.

See: File Properties *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.90).aspx*